# In Scala, can I override a concrete field containing a list and append something to it in the subclass?

Tags: scala

Here's a simplification of the classes I have:

```
trait RequiredThings {
  val requiredThings: Seq[String]
}

class SimpleCalculator with RequiredThings {
  val requiredThings = List("a", "b")
}

class ComplicatedCalculator extends SimpleCalculator with RequiredThings {
  self: SimpleCalculator =>
  override val requiredThings:List[String] = List("c") ::: self.requiredThings
}
```

In this version, I'm using a self-type annotation, but I'm not completely positive that's the way to go. I think I could probably get it to work by converting `requiredThings` to a method throughout, but I'd like to try it as a field.

**Final solution:**

```
trait RequiredThings {
  def requiredThings: Seq[String]
}

class SimpleCalculator with RequiredThings {
  def requiredThings = List("a", "b")
}

class ComplicatedCalculator extends SimpleCalculator with RequiredThings {
  override def requiredThings:List[String] = List("c") ::: super.requiredThings
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, super calls to methods "inherited" through the self-type are not yet implemented. This will change (somewhat) soon. In the meantime, you should use inheritance instead.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. I've updated the question with the final version of my code.

Comment: "This will change (somewhat) soon". I don't remember from the mailing-list where anyone said that this was likely to change. Could you show me where you got that info?

Thanks.

Comment: @Eric: not sure if this is was ever posted on the mailing list, but I'm on the Scala team, and Martin has ok'd (in principle) such a feature. I just got bogged down with other things in the meantime, and there are some non-trivial implementation issues.

Answer (score 4):

Funny enough, I stepped on the same issue yesterday.

The way self types are implemented currently, if you override a method (or value) there's no way to refer to the overridden method.

The following will loop:

```
class A { def foo = "a" }
trait B { self: A => override def foo = self.foo + "b" }
```

(note: you cannot call `super.foo`, the parent of `B` is `ScalaObject`, not `A`)

I also tried with one more indirection, but the program still loops.

```
class A { def foo = "a"; def fooA = A.this.foo }
trait B { this: A => override def foo = fooA + "b" }
```

There is work going on currently on self types, maybe this will change.

Answer (score 3):

It makes sense to have `requiredThings` as a `def` at least in the `trait` - this will give you more flexibility